# Tensorflow-gpu in Jupyter notebook is not recognizing GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

I have installed cuda, cudann and tensorflow-gpu in jupyter environment and after that i am trying to check if i have gpu support in that environment but in list_local_devices its not showing me gpu. I have geforce 1050 ti gpu in my laptop.

```
import os

os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"]="PCI_BUS_ID"
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="1,2"
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib

print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
import tensorflow as tf
tf.test.is_gpu_available()
```

Answer i am getting is:-

```
[name: "/device:CPU:0"
device_type: "CPU"
memory_limit: 268435456
locality {
}
incarnation: 5705862024723076222
]
False
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe it is better to set the CUDA path like:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}
```

and append it to your local `~/.bashrc`.

Make also sure that CUDA is installed correctly like described [here](https://medium.com/@christoph.schranz/set-up-your-own-gpu-based-jupyterlab-e0d45fcacf43).

The command

```
nvidia-smi
```

should return something like:
[image]

The GPU hardware, CUDA version and NVIDIA-SMI driver must be shown.

I hope this helps!